# How do you load music onto an iPod Touch wirelessly?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, itunes, music, ipod-touch

I'm an Ubuntu and an iPod Touch user. I have a collection of music files on my computer. I would like to be able to wirelessly browse using my iPod Touch my music collection that I have saved on my computer. I would like to then to be able to choose an album and load it wirelessly onto my iPod. Is there a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Jail breaking. Other than that, there is no way to do it as the built-in bluetooth functions don't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way right now is using the [Wi-Fi Sync](http://getwifisync.com/) jailbreak app, but it's only compatible with Windows and Mac, not Linux.